# How do you encrypt data between client and server running in Flash and Java?

Tags: java, flash, encryption, network-programming, client-server

We have a multiclient system where the client is written in Flash and the server is written in Java. Currently, communication is done in Flash by usage of `flash.net.Socket` and the protocol is written in JSON. The server uses a custom port to receive connections and then proceed to talk with each client. As expected, data is sent and received on both fronts as raw bytes, which are then decoded as needed.

We would like to encrypt the communication between clients and server. I have some basic understanding about public/private key encryption, but I do not know what is the best way to exchange keys or what libraries are available (on both languages) to do this.

What would be the best strategy to attack this problem and where should I start looking for libraries/methods to implement this encryption?

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Use ssl/tls. There's an as3 ssl implementation that we've used in several commercial projects. Make sure you create a root cert store for the as3 component and populate it with at least the root ca for your server cert. On the server, use java's built in ssl server socket.

Alternatively, you could do away with the custom server, if this is at all possible, and use https, kind of like you would with Ajax in HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: The as3 ssl/tls implementation that I mentioned is called as3crypto.

Comment: One more thing... Since this server will be only contacted by your own flash client, you can use a self-signed certificate. No need to involve a ca. Just make sure your as3 code trust this cert and this cert only.

Comment: I open a server socket on a custom port, and the Flash application connects to that port to send its Policy File Request, to which the server must respond with the policy file. This wouldn't work if I used Java's SSLServerSocket, would it?

Comment: Another problem is that I use ServerSocketChannel, and I couldn't find something called SSLServerSocketChannel in Java.

Comment: You can handle the PolicyFileRequest in a plain-text socket and then upgrade that connection to SSL. To do this (and to account for ServerSocketChannel) you will need to work directly with SSLEngine in the server, and not one of the SSL-enabled socket classes. It's not a big deal though, SSLEngine was expicitly created to allow SSL to be run through all kinds of communications mediums. You simply pass in and receive ByteBuffer data. Clear text in one direction, SSL traffic in the other.